# Intento resolver este problema

Tags: java, bluej

```
 final class Perro    //Regla 5 (clase final)
 {
private final int codigo; //regla 2
private final String  nombre; //regla 2
private final String  raza; //regla 2

/** true:macho; false:hembra */
private final boolean sexo; //regla 2

Persona propietario;
Perro   pareja;

/** Constructor for objects of class Perro */
public Perro(int c, String n, String r, boolean s, Persona p)
{
    codigo      = c;
    nombre      = n;
    raza        = r;
    sexo        = s;
    propietario = p;
}

public String toString()
{

{
    return String.format("%5d %-12s %-12s %-6s %-30s %-12s",codigo,nombre,raza,
                         (sexo?"Macho":"Hembra"), propietario, pareja.nombre);
}
```

}
}

Intento convertir esta clase a *Inmutable*. Es *Mutable* pero trato de convertirla en *Inmutable*. No sé si me podrían decir ¿qué modificaciones me faltarían aplicando las 5 reglas de conversión de una clase *Mutable* a *Inmutable*?. Como les digo, hice un avance pero no sé que más hacer. Les seré muy agredecido.

Comment: No sé qué 5 reglas son esas, pero tanto `propietario` como `pareja` con accesibles desde fuera de la clase así que podrían ser modificados, porque además no son `final`. Si quieres que la clase sea realmente inmutable, debes hacer que todos sus atributos sean finales. Pareja nunca la asignas así que en el toString va a darte un NPE por cierto.

Comment: Estas son las 5 reglas

Comment: 1. No proporcionar ningún método que permita modificar el
objeto .
2. Usar visibilidad privada para los atributos
3. Definir los atributos como final. Aunque puede no ser
estrictamente necesario si no hay setters, pero si sería
conveniente, ya que también previene la modificación
interna.
4. Usar copia defensiva para las referencias internas a
objetos mutables. Esto implica:
1. No inicializar nunca referencias internas simplemente
copiando una referencia externa, por ejemplo, en los
constructores.
2. No devolver nunca una referencia interna

Comment: Y cual de esas 5 reglas cumple, y cual no? nos estas pidiendo que corrijamos tu ejerecicio, cuando lo que deberias hacer es ir linea por linea verificando que todo eso pase...

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque es una solicitud para que alguien más realice su tarea escolar.

Comment: Tengo una duda en concreto

Comment: Persona propietario;
Perro   pareja;

Comment: son atributos??

Comment: *Persona propietario; Perro pareja* son campos de la clase Perro, pero son referencia  a objetos por lo que debes tratarlos como indica el punto 4.1 . Básicamente se debes crear un nuevo objeto a partir del objeto recibido como parámetro en el constructor o método.